# Export DF to seperate .csv files based on column name

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I want to split a dataframe based on the column name and export it in seperate .csv files. How can i do this?

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
import io
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Your Keywords Clustered.csv']))
df_list = [d for _, d in df1.groupby(['Cluster_Name'])]
print(df_list)
```

Example .csv file:

```
a,1
a,2
a,3
b,4
b,5
b,5
```

Answer (score 0):

If new filenames are henerated from names of groups use `for loop` with [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
for name, d in df1.groupby(['Cluster_Name']):
    d.to_csv(f'{name}.csv', index=False)
```

If need remove `Cluster_Name` column in each file (because same value):

```
for name, d in df1.groupby(['Cluster_Name']):
    d.drop(['Cluster_Name'], axis=1).to_csv(f'{name}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: how do i download all the individual csv files at once?